# XCFramework add third party library with Swift package manager duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks, xcframework

Hi there i have the following usecase and have been building a couple days and finally got a bad solution that i don't really link and would really need some assistance on. Would be much appreciated if anyone helps out.

What i have:

I have a framework that uses Alamofire as a dependency with Swift package manager.
I build this framework for distribution with Alamofire it's automatically embedded and i want to make it not embeded just to use it for development until the other project uses it and adds it there.
Next step is add it to the other project. If i don't add Alamofire in the new project there is no issue.
If i add Alamofire there is a duplicate symbols. Anyone have a suggestion how to fix this? I currently don't have a good approach i tried out pretty much everything and as far as i understand it's in development still the SPM...

Example: MyFramework uses Alamofire with SPM and App uses SPM with Alamofire i get duplicate symbols.

What i expect:

A way to be able to add Alamofire into my framework project to use it for development. After when i generate my xcframework and add it to the next project to add the Alamofire lib there and to work without duplicate symbols.

Much appreciated any info.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out @_implementationOnly import Alamofire instead of import Alamofire

This will not expose import Alamofire as public interface in .swiftmodule

Comment: I figured out a solution already and i am using cocoapods in any condition i tried what you suggested and it gave me the same problem...

Comment: @nikiizvorski could you give me a brief steps on how you achieve this with cocoapod? I'm using SPM and I'm having trouble to include/export third party static framework inside my xcframework. Thanks.

Comment: You have to let cocoapods manage dependency. And install dependency over cocoapod if you do it with SPM you will always have an isssue unfortunately. At least for now that's the case. I am using the cocoapods with use-framework option which enables and pulls all the xcframework for the libs i need.